# How to search and replace multiline string in files using linux commands

Tags: regex, linux, sed, find

i have many files which contain similar string which is multiline string for example :

```
<script> var i = 100
         var j = 200
         var x = 1000 </script>
```

and it can be look like this:

```
<script> var i = 100
var j = 200
var x = 1000 </script>
```

or

```
<script> var i = 100

         var j = 200

         var x = 1000 </script>
```

and i want to replace it with

```
<script> var i = 100
         var j = 200
         var x = xxxx </script>
```

Notice that the line can be also none spaced and sometimes it can be tabs

The case i have problem is the multiline , if it was simple one line it easir ,

Comment: In which context multi line is a problem? Please post your tried solution.

Answer (score 0):

Multi line replacements are easy in perl:

```
perl -0 -pe 's/<script>\s*var\s+i\s+=\s+100\s+var\s+j\s+=\s+200\s+var\s+x\s+=\s+1000\s+<\/script>/<script> var i =100\n         var j =100\n         var x = xxxx <\/script>/g' input-file
```

Or (slightly more readable):

```
   perl -0 -pe 's/<script>\s*
    var\s+ i\s+ =\s+ 100\s+
    var\s+ j\s+ =\s+ 200\s+
    var\s+ x\s+ =\s+1000\s+
    <\/script>/<script> var i =100\n         var j =100\n         var x = xxxx <\/script>/gx' input-file
```

Comment: `-0777` is recommended for slurping entire file... `-0` will use ASCII NUL character as separator, which probably is not an issue here.. at least add a note

Comment: question has linux tag, so the `-0` trick can be used with GNU sed as `sed -z`

Comment: Any way to edit the same file ? the -0 is printing the change to stdout

Comment: In perl, if you want to modify the file directly you can add `-i` to the call.